# GCP Cloud Auth Proxy connection reset by peer

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-run

When I ran locally `python3 manage.py runserver` from one terminal, and from another terminal is the auth proxy.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 
failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

Out of nowhere when I try to connect to the Cloud SQL using auth proxy I get the below error:
cloud_sql_proxy -instances=gcloud-xx-yz:europe-west3:mydb=tcp:5432

I tried with the latest version of auth proxy but had no luck, same issue. I know it is pretty stupid trying with the latest version but it does not hurt to try it at least.

```
2023/06/19 21:44:02 Listening on 127.0.0.1:5432 for gcloud-xx-yz:europe-west3:mydb
2023/06/19 21:44:02 Ready for new connections
2023/06/19 21:44:02 Generated RSA key in 122.002994ms
2023/06/19 21:44:18 New connection for "gcloud-xx-yz:europe-west3:mydb"
2023/06/19 21:44:18 refreshing ephemeral certificate for instance gcloud-xx-yz:europe-west3:mydb
2023/06/19 21:44:19 Scheduling refresh of ephemeral certificate in 54m59.590187s
2023/06/19 21:44:19 couldn't connect to "gcloud-xx-yz:europe-west3:mydb": read tcp 172.30.21.57:57791->xx.xx.xx.xx:3307: read: connection reset by peer
```

I have no clue where this IP is coming from `172.30.21.57`. This is not the ip from VPC (Not the CIDR range I am using at least) nor from my local computer.

I tried with `--private-ip` but the same issue pops up.

I read about `Occasionally outbound connections will be reset due to infrastructure updates` from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#connection-reset-by-peer) but I do not think this is the issue in my case.

I basically ran out of ideas to resolve this. I read a lot about resolving this issue but could not get anywhere. Apparently, the issue is that I can not talk to CloudSQL from my local development environment. Note that, for the same app, I did use auth proxy a few dozen times, if not a hundred times, never saw this issue before. I would appreciate it if you can guide me in the right direction, or if you need more info please I am ready to update the question.

Note that the same database I used for GKE AutoPilot with workload identity (to run cloud auth proxy as sidecar with my application container) worked fine. Using a cloud shell I am able to connect to the database, allowing my home IP I can connect to the database but from the Django app, it does not work. I am using Postgres 14, and Django 3.2

Comment: Most likely `172.30.21.57` is the IP address assigned to your Cloud Run container instance. Your question is confusing. I cannot tell which parts of your question are generated where (local, Cloud Run, etc). I am not sure why you are using the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy with Cloud Run. Try editing your post to clarify.

Comment: I have updated the question. I basically use the Cloud SQL directly as a backend database instead of using the local PostgreSQL installed on my PC. This is much easier for the development work as I do not have to later restore data from the local database to the cloud database.

Comment: Have you considered that your router or ISP is closing the connection? That is a very common problem. Your last comment and last edit did not clarify or improve anything.